# pub sub zmq in different applications

Tags: zeromq

can we use pub sub in zeromq to different applications, meaning pub is different application and sub is another app. i am trying to work out the same but no luck as sender is metatrader4 using http://codebase.mql4.com/7147 and sub is the simple client.js running by nodejs.

below is my client.js

```
var zmq = require('zmq');
var socket = zmq.socket('sub');

console.log("Connecting to Currency Stream....");

socket.connect('tcp://127.0.0.1:2027');

socket.subscribe("alpha");


socket.on('message', function (data){
    console.log("Receiving Data...");
    console.log(data.toString());
});
```

regards

Comment: Are you using ZmqSocket.js? http://zeromq.org/bindings%3ajavascript , also, please show code from sending side.

Answer (score 0):

i am using nodejs binding, below is the main code under mt4 init() method

```
int init(){

Print("using zeromq version "+z_version_string());
context = z_init(1);
publisher = z_socket(context,ZMQ_PUB);

if(z_bind(publisher,"tcp://127.0.0.1:2001") == -1)
    return(-1);

z_send("alpha", "Currency Pair Stream Connected");

}
```

Comment: Does zsend() do a sendMore() internally with the topic name? Btw, the ports are not consistent